# Difference between a plain array of Validator functions and using Validators.compose on the array

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am wondering what the exact difference is between a plain array of validator functions such as the example below (taken from the official [angular 2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html)):

```
  buildForm(): void {
    this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
      'name': [this.hero.name, [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(4),
          Validators.maxLength(24),
          forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i)
        ]
      ],
      'alterEgo': [this.hero.alterEgo],
      'power':    [this.hero.power, Validators.required]
    });
    this.heroForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));
    this.onValueChanged(); // (re)set validation messages now
  }
```

and using a **`Validators.compose`** function on that array (see [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/Validators-class.html#!#compose-anchor)).

I was not able to figure that out from the documentation. Can someone please explain what the difference is in terms of behavior, implementation, etc. ?

Answer (score -1):

When we use simply array notation like

```
this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
    'name': [this.hero.name, [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(4),
            Validators.maxLength(24),
            forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i)
        ]
    ]
});
```

Both the same the compose one is for old support

```
this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
    'name': [this.hero.name, Validators.compose([
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(4),
            Validators.maxLength(24),
            forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i)
        ])
    ] 
});
```

Comment: can you please show this difference is "show"? As I know all validators are executed and angular joins all validator errors of a control into one object. So I do not see any difference. Please explain.

Comment: @grishabh I can't see any difference... [**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/KInLJKZxxflg25N3WQl4?p=info).